# format_suffix_patterns error in django 2.1 and python 3.6.5

Tags: python, django, url-pattern

I'm upgrading from Django==1.11 to Django==2.1 and i revise [Django Rest Framework documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/format-suffixes/) and i can't solve this error.

This line of code:

```
urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns, allowed=['api', 'json', 'xml'])
```

show this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'regex'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to post the `urlpatterns` from your `urls.py`?

Comment: SOLVED with `from django.urls import re_path` and change alls `url(...)` to `re_path(the_same_in_url)`